# different meaning of the word "program"

Tags: meaning

[YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN2oALaRfL4#t=12m36) (just click the link and it will automatically fast-forward to the right time mark for you which is located at about 12 minutes 36 seconds)

Transcript:

> Of, now, fundamental interest to us is such **a program** as I have here. Consider this block of wood.

I don't understand why he calls that piece of demonstration equipment a program. The word simply doesn't have such meaning.

Still picture from the video:

[image]

Comment: He might've said **problem** - "задача". But it does sound like "program"..

Comment: I think he means the (planned) section of the (broadcast) program.

Comment: @DamkerngT. has the right of it. The *program* is the *demonstration* of the concept of stability using that wooden block.

Comment: BTW, this guy is great. An absolute exemplar of mid-20th-century science education in the US (which was one of the best aspects of the mid-20th-century US!). His word choice is a (pleasurable) study unto itself.

Comment: I believe he's using "program" in the sense "arrangement (of pieces, components, elements)". He uses it at 12:14 as well, and I don't think he's referring to the TV show but to the particular set of pieces arranged in a certain way in order to demonstrate the principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program) has a good definition that applies here.

> **program**: a plan of things that are done in order to achieve a specific result

His plan is to stack the prepared blocks.  The result is to show how the center of gravity is raised.